# How to apply Bendixson criterion when divergence is not zero?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have to show that the system $$\begin{align*}\dot{x}&=x(3-2x-2y)\\\ \dot{y}&=y(2-2x-y)\end{align*}$$ doesn't have periodic solutions in the first quadrant of the plane $XY$. I was trying to use Bendixson Criterion, but the divergence of the field is $5 - 6 x - 4 y$, which is zero in some points of the first quadrant. Alternatevely, I thought that it was also valid to multiply the field by some scalar $f(x,y)$ such that $\mathbf{\nabla}\cdot (f(x,y)(\dot{x},\dot{y}))$ is not zero, but I couldn't find it. Can you give me any idea to proceed, please?

Comment: You could try just sketching the phase portrait instead. (By the way, this system is a simple model of “species competition”, if you need a search term.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this problem, one can use the [Dulac criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bendixson%E2%80%93Dulac_theorem) which can be used to disprove the existence of periodic orbits. We note that the $x$ and $y$ axis are invariant and hence trajectories that hit such axis will never be periodic. We then pick the Dulac function $g(x,y)=\frac{1}{xy}$. Then
$$\nabla\cdot(g\textbf{f})=-\frac{1}{x}-\frac{2}{y}<0$$
for all $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2_+$. So by Dulac's criterion no periodic orbits exist in the first quadrant! I hope this helps you and please let me know if you have any follow up questions.